# How to use Tensorflow with a GTX 1050 mobile edition?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently started programming with Tensorflow on python. I wanted to improve the calculation-power using my GTX 1050 in my laptop but i didn't success...

After installing all the required libraries and softwares (CUDA 9.0, CuDNN for CUDA 9.0, imported : tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu...), I tryed basic example from the Tensorflow website :

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
print(sess.run(c))`
```

but this return the following answer (I translate it right after) :

```
2018-05-03 19:15:59.540038: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Device mapping: no known devices.
2018-05-03 19:15:59.543664: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\direct_session.cc:284] Device mapping:

MatMul: (MatMul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-05-03 19:15:59.546930: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\placer.cc:886] MatMul: (MatMul)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
b: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-05-03 19:15:59.547254: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\placer.cc:886] b: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
a: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2018-05-03 19:15:59.547597: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\placer.cc:886] a: (Const)/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
[[22. 28.]
[49. 64.]]
```

This heavy message mean that the only device available on my laptop is my CPU but I have a GTX 1050.
I tried to add this line at the begining :
`with tf.device("/device:gpu:0"):`
I spare you all the insult of the command line but it return me this :

```
Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:gpu:0 but available devices are  
[ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. 
Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
```

Is anyone have an idea of the origin of my issue ? Or someone have ever overcome this issue and could help me ?

Comment: I'm confused by this statement "imported : tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu". Did you install tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`?

Comment: As David mentioned, most probably the right version of tensorflow is not being picked up. Usually TF logs some info when it creates devices. Does it attempt to create GPU device? If you don't see it, you can enable some debug logging, e.g. set TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL env var to '3' for most logs (2, 1, for less).

Comment: Hi ! I use pip for both, tensorflow AND tensorflow-gpu, i'll try to set this env var to '3' but nothing had changed ...
Should I dl TF via the website directly ?

Answer (score 0):

If it could help anyone i delete tensorflow-gpu and installed it again via the pip command (pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.8), I specify the version 1.8 and it magically worked.